# page is not properly displaying while printing the same page

Tags: html, angular, printing

I am creating e-challan page in angular material.
This is my html page [html page here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0TZO.png)

it looks proper on html page

and this is my print page [print page here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVTqe.jpg)
it doesn't look properly on print page..
the section bank account number is not properly displayed on print page

```html
<div class="billing-address" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
</div>
<div>
  <h4><strong>Banking Details:</strong></h4>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>Details for the RTGS/NEFT Transaction</h5>
</div>
<table style="width:100%">
  <div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <h4 style="float: left;padding: 8px;">Bank Account No: </h4>
    <tr>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <h4 style="float: left;padding: 8px;">Account Name : </h4>
    <p style="text-align:justify;padding: 6px;"> AMC ADVERTISEMENT RIGHT</p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <h4 style="float: left;padding: 8px;">IFSC Code : </h4>
    <p style="text-align:justify;padding: 6px;"> ICIC0000106</p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <h4 style="float: left;padding: 6px;">Account Bank : </h4>
    <p style="text-align:justify;padding: 8px;"> ICICI Bank</p>
  </div>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

for printing there are specially adapted requests that are written in css.
@media print {}

Comment: thank you for your comment ,can you add some code because of my first time.

Comment: I do not see your CSS file. You can create CSS files and use media print {.yourClassName {width: ...; height: ...}} is similar to the media all and (max-width: 240px) {} parameters when creating the customization page

Answer (score 0):

**your html**

```
<div id="printId" class="billing-address" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
</div>
<div>
  <h4><strong>Banking Details:</strong></h4>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>Details for the RTGS/NEFT Transaction</h5>

</div>
<table style="width:100%">
  <div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <h4 style="float: left;padding: 8px;">Bank Account No: </h4>
    <tr>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
      <td Width="50%">A</td>
    </tr>


  </div>
  <div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <h4 style="float: left;padding: 8px;">Account Name : </h4>
    <p style="text-align:justify;padding: 6px;"> AMC ADVERTISEMENT RIGHT</p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <h4 style="float: left;padding: 8px;">IFSC Code : </h4>
    <p style="text-align:justify;padding: 6px;"> ICIC0000106</p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <h4 style="float: left;padding: 6px;">Account Bank : </h4>
    <p style="text-align:justify;padding: 8px;"> ICICI Bank</p>
  </div>


</table>
```

**In ts file**

```
 print(): void {
            let printContents, popupWin;
            printContents = document.getElementById('printId').innerHTML;
            popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
            setTimeout(()=> {
                popupWin.document.open();
                popupWin.document.write(`
         <html>
            <head>
              <style>           @media print {   @page { margin:21px 35px 35px 35px}   body { padding: 200px;margin: 200px;zoom:72%}  } </style>

            </head>
    // This will bring your css file from your header.
             ${document.querySelector('head').innerHTML}
        <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
          </html>`
                );
                popupWin.document.close();
            },10);
        }
```

You can simply print what ur display shows. even css.